# PySide QTableView setData for multiple cells

Tags: python, qt, pyside, qtableview, qabstracttablemodel

I'm using a `QTableView` and sub-classed a `QAbstractTableModel`. When editing a cell I noticed that `QAbstractTableModel.setData` only goes through the last selected cell. Is there a way to get `setData` to work with multiple (selected) cells?

As an example of usage:

- Select four cells from the table.
- Begin edit on one cell.
- Input a value and hit enter to commit.
- Have value modify all four cells (currently it just modifies the cell that is selected last)

I tried sub-classing `closeEditor`, then looping through `selectedIndexes` to call them with `setData`, but I don't know how to get the user's input value from `closeEditor`.

Here's my attempt, almost got it, just need the input value.

```
def closeEditor(self, editor, hint):
    is_cancelled = (hint == QtGui.QAbstractItemDelegate.RevertModelCache)

    if not is_cancelled:
        for index in self.selectedIndexes():
            if index == self.currentIndex():
                continue

            input_value = ??? # Don't know how to get this from here!

            self.model().setData(index, input_value, QtCore.Qt.EditRole)

    return QtGui.QTableWidget.closeEditor(self, editor, hint)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `editor` in the `closeEditor` signal is the widget that was used for editing.

If that is, for example a `QLineEdit` you can read the text of it through its `text` property.

One way to retrieve the property value is through QObject's property API

```
value = editor.property("text")
```

Comment: The editor is a `QWidget`, so there's no text property.

Comment: As I wrote: if the widget is an `QLineEdit` then it has a text property. I.e. it depends on which widget is being used as the editor. The default delegate used line edits for text, spin boxes for numbers and so on

Comment: Which one does it use then? What's the classname of `editor`? I.e. the value of `editor.metaObject().className()`?

Comment: `editor.metaObject().className()` is `QExpandingLineEdit`. Though `type(editor)` is `QWidget`, so I can't just call `editor.text` like you were suggesting as it doesn't exist. Is the value stuffed inside `editor().metaObject()` somewhere? I checked its documentation but can't really find a way.

Comment: @GreenCell. The answer given here is technically correct. A `QExpandingLineEdit` is an internal Qt class which is a subclass of `QLineEdit`. There seems to be a bug in PySide, because it should pass an instance of `QLineEdit` to `closeEditor`, rather than a `QWidget`. The same code works correctly in PyQt4 (i.e. it passes a `QLineEdit`).

Comment: I guess there's no solution with PySide then? I did use PySide as a tag instead of PyQt ;)

Comment: @GreenCell I had assumed that Python would either access the property through its "duck typing" or at least have a way to cast. But even if Python can't do casts and can't access properties like that, then it should still be possible to call `QObject::property()`

Comment: @KevinKrammer Sorry for being snarky earlier, it's just when I see your answer my immediate response is... duh. It seems like a bug with PySide, maybe missing something to collect the proper editor. I'm able to get the user's input inside `closeEditor` using `editor.property("text")`. Could you add this to your answer for PySide users? Then I'll accept it, thank you!

Comment: @KevinKrammer. It's PySide's job to cast `QWidget* editor` to a `QlineEdit*` before passing a wrapper object to Python. It cannot simply cast to `QExpandingLineEdit*`, because that is an internal Qt class which PySide cannot wrap. So some special handling would be required to cast to the right base-class (i.e. it won't just happen automatically).

Answer (score 0):

**Edit: I was using this as a workaround as there was a bug in PySide where `editor` was only returning a `QWidget`. Please look at Kevin Krammer's answer!**

Though it's a slight work around, the solution I have so far seems to be working fine. Please let me know if there's a better way, this is a bit long-winded.

In `closeEditor` I make every cell pass through `setData` with `None` as the value.

Then in `QAbstractTableModel` I have a variable there `_input_value` that will store the user's input for the rest of the cells to grab.

```
class TableView(QtGui.QTableView):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(TableView, self).__init__(parent)

    def closeEditor(self, editor, hint):
        is_cancelled = (hint == QtGui.QAbstractItemDelegate.RevertModelCache)

        if not is_cancelled:
            for index in self.selectedIndexes():
                if index == self.currentIndex():
                    continue

                # Supply None as the value
                self.model().setData(index, None, QtCore.Qt.EditRole)

        # Reset value for next input
        if self.model()._input_value is not None:
            self.model()._input_value = None

        return QtGui.QTableWidget.closeEditor(self, editor, hint)


class TableModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(TableModel, self).__init__(parent)

        self.main_widget = parent

        self._input_value = None

    def setData(self, index, value, role):
        # Triggers if user cancelled input
        if value is None and self._input_value is None:
            return False

        if self._input_value is None:
            # The last selected cell will pass through here to store the value.
            self._input_value = value
        else:
            # All other cells will pass None, so just grab our stored value.
            value = self._input_value

        # Do whatever you want with value now

        return True
```